# Differential equations: IVP application

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am given $$y'=0.05y-800$$
I am asked to:

(a) Find all constant solutions of the differential equation.

(b) Suppose $y = M$ is your constant solution from (a). Plot two solutions of the differential equation where one satisfies $ 0 < y(0) <M$ and the other satisfying $y(0) > M$. Use this sketch for parts (c), (d) and (e).

Here is what I did. For part a) I equated $y'$ to $0$ since I needed the constant solution for $y'$ and i got $y=16000$. For part b, I'm truly confused as to why there are two solutions for this one. I have the key answer for these problems but at some point I don't how they got the answer and my exam is fast approaching. I need to know how. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. the key answer does not provide any solution. It's mere answer to the problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=0.05y-800
$$
$$
\frac{dy}{0.05 y - 800} = dx
$$
$$
\frac{20\,dy}{y-16000} = dx
$$
$$
20\log|y-16000| = x + C_1
$$
$$
\log|y-16000| = \frac x {20} + C_2\qquad(\text{i.e.}~C_2=C_1/20)
$$
$$
|y-16000| = e^{x/20}\cdot C_3\qquad(\text{i.e.}~C_3=e^{C_2}\text{ is a positive constant.})
$$
$$
y-16000 = e^{x/20}\cdot C_4\quad\text{and $C_4$ need not be positive.}
$$
$$
y = 16000 + C e^{x/20}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Your solution to (a) is correct.

For (b), there are actually *infinitely many* solutions $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, each of which corresponds to a different value of $y(0)$. (NB this equation is separable, and one can solve it explicitly by integrating.)

Comment: I got $y(t) = 20e^{\frac{t+c}{20}} + 16000$ ..  where do I proceed? I think I still don't get the idea. :(

Comment: Pick a value for $y(0)$ in $(0, M)$: this value determines the constant $c$ in your equation, and hence a particular solution to the diff. eq.